# React-navigation, how to get routes from navigatorRef

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation with a [top level navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html).

How can I access routes (not only current) from the `NavigationService.js` ?

*rq: a `console.log(_navigator)` crash my app*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are simply there.

```
const back = () => {
  const { routes } = _navigator.state.nav
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your NavigationService is what you will use to navigate to other routes. You will have to import it into the file you want to use it in and start using it

example from the documentation you posted:

```
// any js module
import NavigationService from 'path-to-NavigationService.js';

// ...

NavigationService.navigate('ChatScreen', { userName: 'Lucy' });
```

Comment: this was not my question. Navigate is ok, what I want is to go back to a route (`back({key})`). I don't have the key, I just have a routeName, so I want to access routes from NavigationService to find the key of the desired route.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that from your question. I don't know how to retrieve all route keys, but I think navigate in react navigation v2 pushes a new screen into the stack only if it is not already in the stack. If it already exists it goes back to it. So it seems to me that navigate("RouteName") should work in your case

Comment: I'm not looking for `navigate()` but `back()`, which uses the route key.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#back